# Config two master node when run KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to setup `Kube`'s cluster with 2 master node `10.0.11.108` and `10.0.11.97` (`Ubuntu`) with config `"ai ai"` in `cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh` file.

When I run

```
KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh,
```

it run deployscript in node 10.0.11.97 twice. And become error:

> [sudo] password to copy files and start node: cp: cannot create
>   regular file ‘/opt/bin/etcd’: Text file busy cp: cannot create regular
>   file ‘/opt/bin/kube-apiserver’: Text file busy cp: cannot create
>   regular file ‘/opt/bin/kube-controller-manager’: Text file busy cp:
>   cannot create regular file ‘/opt/bin/kube-scheduler’: Text file busy
>   start: Job is already running: etcd

Comment: I don't believe kube-up supports multi-master deployments. you'll have to do this on your own. Provision 2 masters with the right binaries, provision a loadbalancer in front of them both, and give the ip of the loadbalancer to your kubelets.

Comment: @PrashanthB yep. i want to deploy HA kubernetes cluster. I can't find any guild except:
http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/
but i dont understand it. 
hic, then i think i can start with deploy multi master node in 1 cluster. :((

Answer (score 0):

I setup Kube's cluster with 1 master, run twice, encounter the same error message, 
I modified `utuntu/util.sh`, and get 'Cluster validation succeeded'.

First add `-f` for all cp commands, like this: `cp ~/kube/default/* /etc/default/`  ===> `cp -f ~/kube/default/* /etc/default/`

Then rerun `./kube-up.sh`, you will encounter "start: Job is already running: etcd"

Then modified `utuntu/util.sh`, modify all 'service XXX start' to 'service XXX restart' , and run kube-up.sh, You'll get the success message.